# Destructuring an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I would like to filter an existing array of objects based on certain key/value pairs.  In the following example I would like the result to be a new array of objects with only the id and def fields (assume there can be n fields in an object, so I don't want to explicitly remove abc).  However, if I code it like below, it looks like I have to manually build the new array row by row.  Is there an easier one-liner?

```
  const someArray = [
   {id: 1, abc: 2, def: 3},
   {id:4, abc: 6, def: 8},
   {id: 5, abc: 7, def: 9},
  ];
  const [array0, array1, array2] = someArray;
  const onlyOneRow = (({ id, def }) => ({ id, def }))(array0);
```

Comment: `someArray.map(o => ({ o.id, o.def }))`?

Comment: `someArray.map({ id, def } => { return {id, def} })`

Comment: @hindmost  I assume you mean -> `someArray.map(({id,def})=>({id,def}))`

Comment: @Keith Yeah, you're right

Comment: These suggestions can not filter the array at the same time. if you use `filter(({id,def}) => id == 3)` you can filter by only using id and def.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily generated with the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
const someArray = [
    {id: 1, abc: 2, def: 3},
    {id:4, abc: 6, def: 8},
    {id: 5, abc: 7, def: 9},
];

let res = someArray.map(x => {return {id: x.id, def: x.def}});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `filter` to build a new array that fits your needs. Consider this example:

```
var array1 = [
  {id: 1, abc: 2, def: 3},
  {id:4, abc: 6, def: 8},
  {id: 5, abc: 7, def: 9},
];

// pass a function to filter
const filteredArray = array1.filter(({id,def}) => x.id == 4);

console.log(filteredArray);
// expected output: Array [{id:4, abc: 6, def: 8}]
```

and if you need to change values inside this filtered array you can use map:

```
const mappedArray = output.map(x => {id: x.id, def: x.def});

console.log(mappedArray);
// expected output: Array [{id:4, def: 8}]
```

Comment: _"I would like the result to be a new array of objects with only the id and def fields"_ - How does your answer produce the expected result? O.o

Comment: updated my answer to use the OPs objects instead of integers.

Comment: _"...with **only** the id and def fields"_

Comment: got it. updated the parameter for the filter-function in my answer